# Drawing custom node on line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, nodes, draw, line

Hello helpful community

I am trying to create a custom node to use in industrial drawing symbolizing interrupted parts looking like that :

[image: Broken line]

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,esvect}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{%
    VueInterromp/.style={
      rectangle,
      draw=none,
      minimum height=2cm,
      minimum width=1cm,
      inner sep=2pt,
     append after command={
            (\tikzlastnode.west) -- ($(\tikzlastnode.west)!0.5!(\tikzlastnode.east)+(-0.3,0)$) -- ++(75:1) -- ($(\tikzlastnode.west)!0.5!(\tikzlastnode.east)+(+0.3,0)+(75-180:1)$) -- ($(\tikzlastnode.west)!0.5!(\tikzlastnode.east)+(+0.3,0)$) -- (\tikzlastnode.east)
        }
    }
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[blue,thick] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[pos=0.3,VueInterromp] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Question 1**

And the result is :

[image: failed broken line]

As one could expect, the line appears behind the node. I've tried `fill=white`, it doesn't seem to do the job since it covers the node itself.

If you have an idea to solve the problem or to improve my code I am listening.

Thank you.

**Question 2**

I have noticed also that if the line is not horizontal it doesn't work, `sloped` doesn't cut it, so probably I am not doing it the right way...

```
\draw[blue,thick] (-3,0) -- (0,3) node[pos=0.3,VueInterromp,sloped] {} ;
```

gives :

[image]

**Question 3**

To go further : drawing several lines :

```
\draw[blue,thick] (-3,0) -- (0,0) node[pos=0.3,VueInterromp,sloped] {} -- ++(-1.5,-3) ;
```

gives :

[image: continuity failed]

You see the next line draw starts a bit after the node instead of the end of the line like I'd wish. Got an idea for that ?

**Question 3.5**

Have a look at what cycle does :

```
\draw[blue,thick] (-3,0) -- (0,0) node[pos=0.5,VueInterromp,sloped] {} node[pos=1] {} -- ++(-1.5,-3) -- cycle;
```

gives:

[image: broken cycle]

Any contribution is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: 1) & 2)  I would look at how tikz and  circuitikz uses to[...] to effect electrical components. 3) That definitely looks like a bug.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I tried to have a look at circuitikz's source code, it's utterly unreadable (for me at least).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is much straight to customize the style of `to path`.

VueInterromp has 4 passes about the custom part:

- location of the center point
- half width of the part / length of the path (fixed width is ok, but a bit more complicated)
- angle between the outer side and the path
- length of outer side

And we need to calculate the slope of the path to get the slop of the outer side.

**Proportional width**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  % #1 center pos, #2 half width/path width, #3 angle, #4 length
  VueInterromp/.style n args={4}{to path={
    let \p1 = (\tikztostart), \p2 = (\tikztotarget) in
    let \n1 = {\x2 - \x1}, \n2 = {\y2 - \y1} in
      \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\diffx}{\n1 / 1cm}}
      \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\diffy}{\n2 / 1cm}}
    let \n{sqrt} = {sqrt((\diffx)^2 + (\diffy)^2)},
      \n{sign} = {\diffy > 0 ? 1 : (\diffy < 0 ? -1 : (\diffx > 0 ? 1 : -1))} in
    let \n{ang} = {\n{sign} * acos(\diffx / \n{sqrt})} in
    \foreach \pos in {#1} {
      % left part
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!\pos - #2!(\tikztotarget)$)
      -- ++({\n{ang} + #3}:#4)
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!\pos!(\tikztotarget)$)
      % right part
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!\pos + #2!(\tikztotarget) + ({\n{ang} + #3 + 180}:#4)$)
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!\pos + #2!(\tikztotarget)$)
    }
    -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
  }}
}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \a [evaluate=\a as \x using \a / 14] in {1, ..., 12}{
    \draw (0, 0) \pgfextra{\edef\temp{\x}}
      to[VueInterromp={\temp}{.05}{70}{2mm}] ++({\a * 30}:3)
      to[VueInterromp={.5}{.1}{60}{2mm}] ++({\a *30 - 90}:1); % use ++ instead of +
  }
  \draw (-5, -5) to[VueInterromp={.2, .5, .8}{.08}{70}{1cm}] (5, -5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Fixed width**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  % #1 center pos, #2 half width, #3 angle, #4 length
  VueInterromp/.style n args={4}{to path={
    let \p1 = (\tikztostart), \p2 = (\tikztotarget) in
    let \n1 = {\x2 - \x1}, \n2 = {\y2 - \y1} in
      \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\diffx}{\n1 / 1cm}}
      \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\diffy}{\n2 / 1cm}}
    let \n{sqrt} = {sqrt((\diffx)^2 + (\diffy)^2)},
      \n{sign} = {\diffy > 0 ? 1 : (\diffy < 0 ? -1 : (\diffx > 0 ? 1 : -1))} in
    let \n{ang} = {\n{sign} * acos(\diffx / \n{sqrt})} in
    \foreach \pos in {#1} {
      % left part
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!\pos!(\tikztotarget) - (\n{ang}:#2)$)
      -- ++({\n{ang} + #3}:#4)
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!\pos!(\tikztotarget)$)
      % right part
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!\pos!(\tikztotarget) + (\n{ang}:#2) + ({\n{ang} + #3 + 180}:#4)$)
      -- ($(\tikztostart)!\pos!(\tikztotarget) + (\n{ang}:#2)$)
    }
    -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
  }}
}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \a [evaluate=\a as \x using \a / 14] in {1, ..., 12}{
    \draw (0, 0) \pgfextra{\edef\temp{\x}}
      to[VueInterromp={\temp}{1.5mm}{70}{2mm}] ++({\a * 30}:3)
      to[VueInterromp={.5}{.1}{60}{2mm}] ++({\a *30 - 90}:1); % use ++ instead of +
  }
  \draw (-5, -5) to[VueInterromp={.2, .5, .8}{.8cm}{70}{1cm}] (5, -5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Change log**

- 5.31-1 change `atan2` to `acos` to judge the direction of the path
- 5.31-2 change example
- 6.1 add for loop to draw multiple vueinterromps

Comment: I was hoping there would be a generic way to create a node that would follow a line with 'sloped' and avoid calculating by hand, but I guess it's a too precise need for it to be user-friendly. Anyway, thank you very much for your work, I'll test it out and use it.

Comment: I understand '(\A)!#1!(\B)' but not quite '(\A)!#1 + #2!(\B)' , could you explain to me what it evaluates ?
I suppose '(\A)!#1' if a fraction of the vector \A , but #2 is a length....

Comment: In Proportional width version, #2 is the ratio of half of the width of the custom part to the length of the whole path, so #1 - #2 is the end of part near to the start point of the path, and #1 + #2 is the end of the part near to the end point of the path

Comment: Can I put two/several on the same path ? or do I have to use intermediate points ?

Comment: Now passing a pos list is supported.

Comment: Great work ! Thanks again.